# html auto tag completion

Tags: html, ide, tags

Is there any IDE that lets or complete the tag immediately ?

eg. once i finish writing <html>, it will insert </html> automatically.

this will reduce time and also help to reduce error.

I am working in windows and would like to have some free editors/IDE.

I am just starting to learn some html and web programming, so any tips is welcome.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

checkout Aptana - aptana.com

And you can install Zen coding for fast code-writting - http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/
Short video - http://vimeo.com/7405114

Answer (score 3):

Yes, most IDEs do that.

To give just one example, [Visual Studio Web Developer 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/).

Could you be more specific about what kind of IDE you need if you want a suggestion of an IDE more suitable for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are many - first of all any XML editor will do it
(or at least support XHTML (with <BR/> and <HR/> instead of <BR> and <HR>)).

Check out HTML editors in softpedia.com

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans: http://netbeans.org/

Comment: The answer is simply the name of the IDE, which I provided.

Comment: take a look here please: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: However in this case it's fine (IMO). But on the review tool it looks like any other link-only answers (The question's title doesn't help either).

Comment: The referenced meta question is referring to answers that are actually answered in the link. The worry is that since the pertienent information of the answer is only contained in the linked webpage, that the answer can be lost of that website is taken down. In this case, my answer is simply "Netbeans". Then, I provide a link to the Netbeans site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mac use [textmate](http://macromates.com/) or on windows use [e-text editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/). These editors have very good support for HTML, ROR, PHP and stuff and reduces lot of typing. like head followed by tab will create a head tag, and very useful and time saving key binding and shortcuts.